# Angular Clarity Icon cannot bind to CSS shape attribute within an ngFor loop

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I am trying to build a list of links where the links are provided from a rest call.  The resulting list of links will contain a URL and a type identifier.  I am trying to display the icons using an ngFor loop and am using the stock Clarity icon set:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-link [ngForOf]="links" let-j="index" >
    <clr-icon shape={{link.icon}} height="42" width="42"></clr-icon>
    ...
```

However when i run this i get:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'shape' since it isn't a known property of 'clr-icon'.
1. If 'clr-icon' is an Angular component and it has 'shape' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'clr-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

Is there any way to bind shape to the icon in this scenario or are CSS attributes a no-go?

Comment: What's wrong with the idiomatic `*ngFor="let link of links"`? The message is telling you that there is no known component with `clr-icon`as seclector. You probably forgot to import the module declaring this component inside your own NgModule. Also, the proper way of passing an input is `[shape]="link.icon"`.

Comment: clr-icon is just a css tag in this scenario which just needs the css linked at the root which works fine without the shape binding, RE the ng-template, I needed the index.

Comment: Then the idiomatic syntax is `*ngFor="let link of links; index as j"`. clr-icon is a non-standard HTML tag. So either it's supposed to be an Angular componet, or it's supposed to be a web component. If it's not supposed to be any of those, then use a standard tag, like span or div. But span or div don' hae any shape attribute, which means that it's most probably an angular component or a web component. So you need to import its NgModule, or do as the error message says.

Comment: And reading https://vmware.github.io/clarity/icons/clarity-icons confirms that it's a web component. Do as the error message says.

Comment: There was a wall of red so I did not actually fully grasp the error, I thought fundamentally you cannot bind to CSS elements atall.  But your suggestion worked, needed to add the schema.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use attribute binding to do that.

`<clr-icon [attr.shape]="link.icon" height="42" width="42"></clr-icon>`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might not have included the ClarityModule into your NgModule, which would handle registering the `clr-icon` element with your module. If you use feature modules, you'll still have to add ClarityModule to your imports for any feature module that uses Clarity or you get errors like this.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to JB for pointing me in the right direction, it was a simple case of needing to add:

```
schemas: [
  CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
]
```

to the parent NgModule.